# Docusign microsoft dynamics 365 install not working

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign \ Microsoft Dynamics 365 Not Working: We are trying to resolve 2 issues

- Install via demo account to get install working
- Uninstall of Docusign instances sitting in dyn 365

Answer (score 0):

Please contact DocuSign Customer Support via the web or telephone.

See https://support.docusign.com/